# How do you change the color of an Internet Calendar in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, colors, calendar

It's easy to change the color of your personal calendar...
Tools > Options > Calendar Options... > Default color.

However, it seems when adding an internet calendar, or viewing another shared calendar from a user on my domain, Outlook randomly chooses the color.  Is there a way for the user to choose the color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now possible using Outlook 2010.

1. Select the calendar you wish to change.
2. Select the View tab on the ribbon.
3. Click the 'Color' button and select the desired color.

[image: Outlook Calendar Color]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it seems that you cannot decide on the background colors for additional calendars (for Outlook 2007 and earlier).

Here's a short answer (to the same question as yours) from an MS Outlook MVP, dated March 2010 (found [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/background-color-outlook-2007-help-193091301.html)):

> No. Outlook assigns the color.
>
> Diane Poremsky [MVP - Outlook]

Wish I had better news for you.

Comment: Damn.  That sucks.

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of a shared or internet calendar- open the calendar you would like to change the color of, go to `options--> calendar options --> set default color --> save`

if you would like all of your calendars to be the same color click the "use selected color on all calendars" box.

Comment: Hi Hayley.  Your answer is good but doesn't precisely solve the problem.  It inspired me to write an answer that does given the new functionality built into Outlook 2010. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

Just knowing this may help... there is a specific sequence of colors Outlook uses when applying these colors. I have tested and found on mine to be original calendar: blue, then green, pink, grey, teal, purple, bluish green, red, and brown.

If you uncheck to hide, and then check to show your calendars, you can apply the color in the order specified by Outlook's sequence. If you know your calendars will always be checked, you can add as many subscriptions as it takes to get to your chosen color and then delete the unwanted ones. I know, this is a crazy work-around, but I did it because I wanted specific colors.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is the 2007 work-around. Obviously the 2010 version has the feature and the work-around is not needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is late but it works so in case any other people is interested...
On Outlook 2007 you can use the Automatic Formatting.
Add a rule and on the advanced tab, set    Field: "In Folder"    Condition: "Contains"    Value: "NameOfYourCalendar"